# Rsync failed to set times on "/foo/bar/.": Permission denied (13

Tags: rsync

rsync: failed to set times on "/foo/bar/.": Permission denied (13)
./

sent 295 bytes  received 1,058,555 bytes  111,457.89 bytes/sec
total size is 156,372,994,581  speedup is 147,681.91
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1637) [generator=3.1.1]

I get this error when I ran rsync. Also I could see size discrepancy between two rsync directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-O` / `--omit-dir-times` to your command line. This tells rsync to avoid trying to set modified times files.